# How to optimize Go Confluent Kafka consumer to catch up 500 millions lagging messages?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic with 12 partitions, and that topic is received transaction messages from the frontend system all day long.
And currently I have an ETL application to consume the messages on that topic by using default `github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka`.
This ETL is deployed into 12 pods of Kubernetes, so each pod will specifically consume on each partition.

The consumer configuration is:

```
`consumer, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
"bootstrap.servers":  config.CONFIG["KAFKA_SERVERS"],
"sasl.username":      config.CONFIG["KAFKA_USER"],
"sasl.password":      config.CONFIG["KAFKA_PASSWORD"],
"group.id":           config.CONFIG["KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP"],
"session.timeout.ms": 300000,
"auto.offset.reset":  "latest",
"security.protocol":  "SASL_SSL",
"sasl.mechanism":     "PLAIN",

// Consumer Tuning
"fetch.min.bytes":         1,
"max.poll.interval.ms":    300000,
"auto.commit.interval.ms": 10000,
"heartbeat.interval.ms":   100000,
})`
```

But my ETL application runs unproperly in last 1-2 weeks, and the messages have lagged approx. 500.000.000 records. with the production speed from the front application, and my ETL's consumption speed, the lag is still happen and not catch up.

[image: The massive lagging]

What can I do to speed up the consumer to decrease the lagging number?

Please don't hesitate to comment if anything in my question is unclear.

I have optimized the code, but lagging still massively happen. and I expect to get an insight what best Go consumer code to decrease this lagging.

Comment: "I have optimized the code" is your Optimize the code made by consumer business? if  yes. optimize more or delete  business or add consumers

Comment: Yes, optimizing the code base on Confluent best practice. about the consumers, currently 12 pods of Kube for 12 partitions, do I need to add more consumers?

Comment: It depends on your business, if the business is not important, such as Logging,you can delete the logging busines to decrease this lagging. if important, you can optimize the  business code or add consumers

Comment: Let me try it first, which one should remove from the code. because several parts are mandatory required for the process.

Comment: We can't see your processing logic, so we cannot answer that. But you cannot add more consumers than partitions, so no, that is not an option